# nginx v1.10.2 Passenger 403 Homebrew Upgrade

Tags: ssl, nginx, homebrew, passenger

Multiple virtual hosts on my workstation, just stopped working.  Upon an update of `nginx` to v1.10.2 and a new `Passenger` `locations.ini` file pointer in the `nginx.conf` file, I'm getting `403 Forbidden` permissions errors on all of these vhosts.  No clue what to look at.

```
passenger_root /usr/local/opt/passenger/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;
```

But, `which ruby`:

```
/Users/rich/.rbenv/shims/ruby
```

So I changed that directive to the one above.  Restart `nginx`, and still the same.  The error reported:

```
2017/10/23 19:51:36 [error] 10863#0: *61 directory index of "/Library/WebServer/Documents/alpha/public/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: alpha.local, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "alpha.local"
```

Permissions haven't changed ever.  Not to mention they are relaxed (only seen by me):

```
drwxrwxrwx  20 rich  admin   680B Jun 17 01:52 HQ
cd HQ:
drwxr-xr-x   8 rich  admin   272B Jul 12 17:32 public
```

`nginx.conf`:

```
user                                root admin;
worker_processes                    8;

error_log                                   /usr/local/var/log/error.log  debug;
pid                                         /usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections          1024;
}


http {
#       index               index.html index.erb;
        access_log          /usr/local/var/log/access.log;

        passenger_root /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.1.11/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
        passenger_ruby /Users/rich/.rbenv/shims/ruby;
        passenger_friendly_error_pages on;

        include /usr/local/etc/nginx/servers/*;     # see below
}

server {
    listen                      80;
    server_name                 alpha.local;
    include                     /usr/local/etc/nginx/mime.types;
    access_log                  /usr/local/var/log/access_alpha.log;
    error_log                   /usr/local/var/log/error_alpha.log  debug;
    error_page  404     /404.html;
    root                            /Library/WebServer/Documents/alpha/public;
    passenger_enabled   on;
    passenger_base_uri  /;

    location / {
        autoindex               off;
        # try_files             $uri $uri/ /index.html?$query_string;
#       index                       /;
#       allow                       192.168.1.0/24;
    }
    location = /img/favicon.ico { access_log off;}

}
```

nginx error log:

```
2017/10/24 15:35:39 [error] 10868#0: *86 directory index of "/Library/WebServer/Documents/alpha/public/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: alpha.local, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "alpha.local"
```

Odd stuff.  Any ideas appreciated how to get all this serving again properly.  It seems permissions were completely thrown off, and I'm not sure if it was the `nginx` update or not.  Cheers

==============

Update 2: (changed alpha/HQ).  Also, replicated on a completely separate box.  Homebrew update, trips over `nginx`'s dependency on `openssl`, which wants to update to version 1.1.  I've posted in Github there.  While I have no proof, it's the only feedback I have that shows a non-upgrade (still serving 1.12.0 instead of 1.12.2).  So I am thinking it is that.

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/19810

Comment: Please include your server block for the app, as well as the nginx error log for the issue.

Comment: Your request says the request was to `hq.local` but your server block is for `alpha.local`

Comment: Modified for posting here.  Like I said, all vhosts have done deaf.  I've also replicated this on another box completely.  Homebrew update of `openssl` to v1.1 trips and is the current culprit.  I'll update above.

Comment: Nginx with passenger uses `openssl` not `openssl@1.1`, homebrew is usually smart enough to sort out the deps, but it seems that it's confused.

Comment: Recursive dependencies no less.  But it's interesting that it broke the current `1.12.0` install.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.  Homebrew issue, conditional if `Passenger` is installed, choosing version of `openssl` (`openssl`, `openssl@1.1`).